# Calculated column returning all results

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a colleague table (named 'colleagues') which lists all of the colleagues in the department. I have another table (named 'cases') which lists all of the cases worked by all of the colleagues. In the cases table, there is a column called 'outcome' which will be either Good, Satisfactory or Bad depending on how well the case was dealt with.

colleagues table:

[image]

cases table:

[image]

There is a one to many relationship between the colleague table and the cases table. I am trying to create a calculated column in the colleague table which will sum how many 'Good' outcome cases they had in total. This the calculated column formula I have:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('cases'), FILTER('cases', 'cases'[outcome]="Good")
```

This calculated column is just adding all of the 'Good' cases for everyone rather than just the individual colleague. See calculated column below with column name 'Good':

[image]

The expected behavior is that the column would calculate the number of 'Good' cases each colleague had. This is the expected outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a calculated column as follows:

```
CountValues =
             CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('cases'),'cases'[outcome]="good")
```

p.s. If this (or another) answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer that helped by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in".

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have implemented this but I am receiving the error "the syntax for 'cases' is incorrect"

Comment: @BailP I've edited the answer for u. It will work now. Incase if it doesn't work, you have to check whether the table and column names are correct

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that doesn't involve `CALCULATE` is

```
COUNTROWS( FILTER( RELATEDTABLE('cases'), 'cases'[outcome]="Good" ) )
```